# Is there an Elastic 7 api method for getting two documents in one request. Not join

Tags: elasticsearch

For example i have 2 documents in elastic: articles & langs. I want to get data in one request form all of them. It must looks like articles : [data], langs : [data]. Is it possible or i must make two request only?

Comment: Are queries for both the index different?

Comment: No, just get all from both

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ids of the documents, you can use the [`multiget` api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [multisearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) api. This api supports multiple search queries to same/different indexes.

Another approach to get all documents from both indexes can be tagetting both indexes using search api:

```
GET articles,lang/_search
```